# Number of pie slices in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

is there a limitation of number of slices for a pie chart?  I used 2 different methods to create the pie chart: json and csv file.  There should be 17 slices, but only 13 slices are displayed/created.   Please see the data below:

For the json, the data is as follows:[][1]

```
[{"name":"Back - 2005","y":2005,"color":"#ed7d31"},
{"name":"Exempt - 2","y":2,"color":"#a5a5a5"},
{"name":"Cloud - 48","y":48,"color":"#666666"},
{"name":"Discrepancies - 200","y":200,"color":"#ffc000"},
{"name":"Managed - 474","y":474,"color":"#003366"},
{"name":"Managed - NEW - 7","y":7,"color":"#135fa0"},
{"name":"Icon - 5","y":5,"color":"#135fa0"},
{"name":"Non-Managed - 73","y":73,"color":"#ff334d"},
{"name":"Pending - 302","y":302,"color":"#258e60"},
{"name":"Pole - 300","y":3,"color":"#e19090"},
{"name":"Red - 8","y":8,"color":"#5b9bd5"},
{"name":"Cleanup - 20","y":20,"color":"#a9d18e"},
{"name":"Needs - 123","y":123,"color":"#cc99ff"},
{"name":"Valid - 442","y":442,"color":"#548235"},
{"name":"Windows 7 - 9540","y":9540,"color":"#c00000"},
{"name":"Windows 2008- 314","y":314,"color":"#ff0d0d"},
{"name":"Windows 2010- 600","y":600,"color":"#ff02314"}]
```

CSV:
name   y
Back   2005
Exempt  2
Cloud    48
Discrepancies  200
Managed   474
Managed-New   7
Icon        5
Non-Managed 73
Pending 302
Pole 300
Red 8
Cleanup 20
Needs 123
Windows 7 9540
Windows 2008   314
Windows 2010    600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the slices are rendered, but there is not enough space to show every data label. To make more space, you can reduce `padding`:

```
series: [{
  ...,
  dataLabels: {
    padding: 0
  }
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4763/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.padding